# Google Colab - Authorization error to google drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to link my colab to the google drive by this code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It has always worked until today, clicking on the oauth2 link only brings me the following screen

[image: Error 403: access_denied screen]

I have tried logging out all the google accounts, using incognito mode, etc. but none of them works

I would appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to mount or link Google drive in Colab:

1. Connect using Colab itself by click on this icon:
   [image]
2. Connect using these commands :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

**Conclusion**

[image]

Copy the auth code instead of clicking the copy button will solve your issue. It seems java-script compatibility issue within the code of the copy button. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy auth code. After that go back to colab and paste it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> here: [image]

Comment: If My answer helps you to solve your issue, Please up vote and mark it as answer to help others who have the same issue. If still have issues, let me know and i will help you ASAP.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! But turn out its some setting wrong with google family plan that locked the authorization.  But again much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

**Update 17/11/2021**

They have since rolled back so the 'old' method is the default - therefore the fault behind the error I addressed should no longer occur.

However, this solution may still be useful if the fault reemerges, otherwise refer to @AEM's answer for the alternative ways to mount your drive.

**Original Answer**

There is an open Github issue since it seems to have resurfaced - albeit it seems to be as a result of a different cause: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2422

there seems to be a bug in the way the new mount method works,

as per the GitHub thread, you can use the following to use the old method of sign-in, using '_mount' as shown below:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive._mount('/drive')
```